# make pip ignore an existing wheel

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

If a `.whl` is available online, `pip` always installs it rather than compiling from source. However, for some specific module, the wheel happened to be compiled for the next processor generation and doesn't run on a specific machine.

If I command it to just download the package, then it still downloads the wheel rather than source. Does `pip` have some mechanism to override this preference?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye No, this isn't affected by the local cache.

Comment: Pardon me. I think you could do the install directly from `git` if the source has one with `pip install git+https://repourl`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye then I need to somehow manually learn that the package has a git repo online and where it is. FWIW, I can locale the source manually and compile it, all without `pip`.

Comment: also, you should report such a wheel to upstream, clearly its version is not tagged correctly

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it's tagged "win32". I'm not aware of any more specific (e.g. "ix86") markings existing for wheels. Are there?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try using

```
pip install <package> --no-binary :all:
```

---

You can find this option (and the values it takes) in `pip install --help`.

There's also the `--no-use-wheel` option, but that has been deprecated in favour of the above and removed in `pip` `10.0.0`.

Here is reference in official documentation:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-binary

Comment: Ran into this problem with a homebrew Python installation and a wheel for [python-levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) that was built with 4-byte Unicode ([UCS-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)) symbols, whereas my Python was only UCS-2. The traceback I got was similar to that described [here](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/34496-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs4_fromunicode): `undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromUnicode`. Using `pip install --no-binary` to install from source (ignoring the wheel) totally did the trick!

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full but here is the correct link: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-binary

Comment: @TobiasFeil Made the update for you