# How to instruct pip to install a requirement with --no-binary flag

Tags: python, pip

I have an app that I want to package which is dependent on `protobuf`. It is essential that protobuf be installed as such:

```
pip install protobuf --no-binary=protobuf protobuf
```

How can I include this inside my `setup.py`  `install_requires`?

**Note:** My requirements mandate that this process automatically goes through setup.py.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263682/make-pip-ignore-an-existing-wheel) and [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/)

Thus, I've tried including such things in install_requires or requirements.txt to no luck:

```
#requirements.txt
protobuf
--no-binary=protobuf
```

How can I provide the `--no-binary=protobuf protobuf` (which I know are `pip` flags) to the installation of `protobuf` when I'm packaging my app?

**Update:**
What I want is for the protobuf package to be installed the way I mentioned when I install my package this way:

```
`pip install my_package.whl`
```

Answer (score 3):

## Install with a `requirements.txt` file

I guess you can simply add the flag on the same line. This worked for me:

```
# requirements.txt

protobuf --no-binary protobuf
pandas
```

With this `requirements.txt`, protobuf is installed without binaries, whereas pandas is still installed with `.whl`.

By running `pip install -r requirements.txt`, you will have something like:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
Collecting pandas
  ...
Collecting protobuf
  Using cached protobuf-3.17.3.tar.gz (228 kB)
Skipping wheel build for protobuf, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: protobuf, pandas
    Running setup.py install for protobuf ... done
Successfully installed pandas-1.1.5 protobuf-3.17.3
```

## Automatic install inside a packaged library

If you want to include the dependency to `protobuf` with no binary, and you are packaging your library with a `setup.py` file, you can include `package@http://link/to/package.tar.gz` inside the `install_requires` argument of `setup`.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='your package`,
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'click',
        'pyyaml',
        'protobuf@https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.17.3/protobuf-python-3.17.3.tar.gz'
    ]
)
```

This solution's drawback is that it also specifies the the version of the dependency.

Hope this helps !

Comment: do you run `pip install -r requirements.txt`? I want the protobuf to be installed the way I want when I issue: `pip install my_package.whl`

Comment: Yes I do run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. I edited my answer

Comment: That would not suit my situation given that I want to run `pip install my_package.whl`. I want this to be handled in packaging.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Another problem I forgot to mention, in my environment I have no access to the Internet. We do have a mirror of PyPI though.

Comment: On the PyPi page of protobuf, https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/#files, there is an entry for the source code. There should be some similar url in your mirror of PyPi. I would then suggest you to replace the URL I have added in `setup` by yours

Comment: @AmirAfianian Did you manage to make it work ?

Comment: Unfortunately not in the way I wanted. Resolved it on a different level. (Container)