# Pandas read_hdf not working on linux server but locally - python

Tags: python, pandas, linux

I have some code that runs perfectly on my local computer, but when I try to run it on a linux server (connecting via ssh and then I start my docker container), I get the following error messages:

LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
[WARNING] Worker with pid 49 was terminated due to signal 4

At the line where my code breaks, I try to open a file with pandas.read_hdf()

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

[...]
if Path(path_to_file).is_file():
    result = pd.read_hdf(path_to_file, mode='r', key=keyword)
    [...]
```

I do have the file on my server, and I also check with `Path(path_to_file).is_file()` if the file is found (which returns True). I have no idea why it does work locally but not on the server. Any help is really much appreciated and if more information should be provided, please tell me!

Comment: You could compare the Pandas versions on your local computer and on the server, and you could transfer the file to your computer and try to read it there.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Armali, i tried both options, but it still doesnt work..

Comment: So, if it _still doesnt work_ on your local computer, the failure has nothing to do with Pandas versions; it must be due to the content of the file, and help is presumably only possible if you present that file.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear enough. It does work perfectly on my local computer, but on the server, it doesnt work. I checked, that the file is identical on my local machine and on the server, and also the pandas versions are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker solved my problem: Pandas was installed via pip. The precompiled wheel could not be read completely by the server (probably due to a little different CPU). Debian does compile his packages a little different than pypi, which worked in my case. So i removed pandas from my requirements.txt and added the following line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential python3-dev python3-pandas python3-pip && \
    apt-get clean -y && \
```

Note here the `python3-pandas` and the `python3-pip`.

Another option would be to compile pandas, and not use the wheel, which could be done by `pip3 install pandas --no-binary` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38263887/12106282)